# Limiting a single process's memory without children using cgroups

Tags: linux, cgroups

I need to limit memory usage for a process, but ignore all its children. How do I do that? Using cgroups is preferred, but not necessary.

Note: I want to ignore all current and **future** children of the process. I know that it can escape the limits, but that's what I need.

Comment: Do mean to ignore all its existing children? You can do that with `prlimit`. But if you mean to ignore any future children, that doesn't make much sense, as the process could easily escape that limit by forking and exiting.

Comment: I'm trying to limit a legitimate program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case `prlimit --as=<virtual memory in bytes>` helped. It doesn't always work correctly (because virtual memory is tricky), so use with caution. You may also want to set a soft limit instead with `prlimit --as=<limit>:`

### Examples:

#### Start a process with virtual memory limited to 2 GB (both soft and hard limits)

```bsh
prlimit --as=2147483648 -- process --with args
```

#### Start a process with virtual memory limited to 2 GB (only soft limit)

```bsh
prlimit --as=2147483648: -- process --with args
```

#### Start a process with virtual memory limited to 2 GB (only hard limit)

```bsh
prlimit --as=:2147483648 -- process --with args
```

#### Limit an existing process to 2 GB of virtual memory

```bsh
prlimit --as=2147483648 --pid=<process pid>
```

#### Limit current shell to 2 GB of virtual memory

```bsh
prlimit --as=2147483648 --pid=$$
```

Comment: @Peregrino69 I edited the answer to be more informative. Thanks!

Comment: @Peregrino69 Added many examples

Comment: Wow! You just basically taught me how to use prlimit :-D I'll remove my redundant comments :-) I upvoted the answer :-)

Comment: I didn't even know about it before today :D

Comment: ... and upvoted comment :-D

Comment: @Peregrino69 Is it even possible to upvote comments? 

Comment: Yap - it's the little arrow above the flag on the left hand side. Apparently I made a li'l bu-bu there... it's intended for upvoting _useful_ comments i.e. ones that add to the answer... ah well, can't un-upvote it anymore :-D